# Differential of $p$-norm

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have quick questions about an exercise in differential calculus.
I'm not very good at calculus, so I need you to tell me if the following is right (for the first and the second points) and I need a bit of help for the third point.

First, consider
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{cccc}
\Phi:&(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\
&(v,w)&\mapsto&\|v+w\|_p
\end{array}
\right.$$
where $p > 1$.

1. I need to find where this map is differentiable, so I found the set $A = \{(v,w) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n : v + w = 0_{\mathbb{R}^n}\}$ and I found that $\Phi$ is differentiable on $B = (\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)-A$.
2. I need to find the differential of this map, so I tried to calculate the Jacobian matrix and I obtained (for any point $(v,w) \in B$):
   $$J_{(v,w)}\Phi = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{(v_1+w_1)|v_1+w_1|^{p-2}}{\|v+w\|_p^{p-1}}&\dotso&\frac{(v_n+w_n)|v_n+w_n|^{p-2}}{\|v+w\|_p^{p-1}}&\frac{(v_1+w_1)|v_1+w_1|^{p-2}}{\|v+w\|_p^{p-1}}&\dotso&\frac{(v_n+w_n)|v_n+w_n|^{p-2}}{\|v+w\|_p^{p-1}}\end{pmatrix}$$
3. I need to calculate extrema of the map $\Phi$ on $B$, so if I set
   $$J_{(v,w)}\Phi = 0_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n}$$
   I obtain that for every $i \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$, $v_i + w_i =0$, in other words $(v,w) \in A$. Does it mean that $\Phi$ has no extrema on $B$?